# Nested DataGridView Control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create a nested DataGridView control where there will be two levels of nesting that are open at all times. It will look similar to the picture on this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12657/GridView-inline-Master-Detail-record-display. The difference will be that each subnesting will always be open and it is not necessary to have a way for the user to open/close each nesting. This control will only be used for displaying data, so there will be no need to modify the data directly from this control (even though the user will not modify the data directly it can still be changed).

If this can not be done with DataGridView, is there any other control that would allow for this.

If not does anyone know another way to do this. I can, but they would be tedious to implement. One way would be to add multiple DataGridView controls in sequence (2N DataGridControls for N categories). The other would add it all manually with static controls.

Comment: I strongly recommend WPF for this instead of winforms.

Comment: do you want to make a datagridview as nonedittable, or do you want all the datagridview in a form to be nonedittable?

Comment: How long would it take to learn how to use WPF and then implement this. (I have no knowledge of it.)

Comment: why don't you set the ReadOnly Property of the Datagridview.

Comment: I don't know how the read only setting has anything to do with making a nested control. If it does let me know. I have only mentioned the read only to increase the number of alternative method suggestions of solving this if the nested control can not be done.

Comment: I have checked WPF and wont have time to learn this. Thank you anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will give the answer, but it might make u some door.

```
//button to call function that looks for DatagridView control
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scanDG(this);
}

private void scanDG(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType().Name == "DataGridView")
        {//If current Control is Datagridview then set Readonly to true
            ((DataGridView)ctrl).ReadOnly = true;
        }

        //If a control can contain control scan it and look for Datagridview control
        if (ctrl.HasChildren) scanDG(ctrl);
    }
}
```